# messaging protocol Pubnub or Rabbitmq for Communication in GPS Tracking Application

Tags: android, node.js, angular, rabbitmq, pubnub

What is the best messaging protocol Pubnub or Rabbitmq for Communication in GPS Tracking Application.

**Technologies**

Nodejs(Server Side Application)

Android (Client Mobile Application)

Iphone or IOS Application (Client Mobile Application)

Angular(Admin Dashboard or client Web Application)

I have referred this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-PubNub-and-RabbitMQ) and didn't came to any conclusion

Comment: RabbitMQ and PubNub are designed for two very different challenges. RabbitMQ's strength is backend server to server communication. PubNub is best for massive scale of device to device realtime messaging (device can be anything that speaks http - mobile, web, desktop, server, IoT devices). You may use both in your tech stack to implement your service/app. Stay tuned for a more complete answer from the PubNub Developer Relations team.

Comment: See results from [PubNub Geolocation web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pubnub+geolocation&oq=pubnub+geolo&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0.2207j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - lot's of a good links to review.

Comment: Yaa i know both pubnub and rabbitmq and I have used them. But i want to know performance wise Pubnub or rabbitmq for GPS based tracking system.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub provides easy to use APIs and SDKs to transfer data like GPS location with very low latency. All of PubNub's systems will meet the scale of your application automatically, whether there are 2 clients or 2 million. Every electronic device with an internet connection can use PubNub.

See this recent tutorial for [building an Android Uber/Lyft application using PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-your-own-uber-lyft-app-geolocation-tracking-android/?devrel_so=kaushik), and also this customer case study regarding [realtime GPS maps for Zoomy](https://www.pubnub.com/customers/zoomy/)

The Pub/Sub connection that PubNub provides allows for data to be continuously streamed between one or many devices, illustrated in this example app diagram:

[image]

Comment: Yaa i know both pubnub and rabbitmq and I have used  them. But i want to know performance wise Pubnub or rabbitmq for GPS based tracking system

Comment: I am not entirely sure that RabbitMQ is a solution for your GPS tracking assuming you need to deliver your messages to devices like mobile phones and web browsers. Either way, in the words of Han Solo, "PubNub's fast enough for ya...". 1/4 message delivery guaranteed worldwide, typically averaging < 100ms.

Comment: Is it possible to have a server subscribe to the driver's location? What if I wanted to store location data or whatever data is being streamed?